# Inserting its own size to std::map

Tags: c++, c++14, stdmap

I just encountered a weird bug in my code (C++14) caused by the unexpected (for me at least) behavior of std::map. Here's a simple example demonstrating the behavior:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, int> m;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        m[m.size()] = m.size();
    }
    for(const std::pair<int, int>& e : m) {
        std::cout << e.first << " " << e.second << std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
0 1                                                                                                                                                                            
1 2                                                                                                                                                                            
2 3
```

I was expecting:

```
0 0
1 1
2 2
```

What is going on here? The map first adds a new element with `first` set and only then (when the map's size has already increased) sets `second`? I don't quite understand why this would make sense. Or is there some other explanation? Thanks!

Comment: Isn't this just the `i++ + ++i` problem?

Comment: Which version of C++ are you using?  For this, it matters

Comment: @NathanOliver, I observed this with C++14 (added to my question). I wasn't expecting it would matter.

Comment: @PetriHirvonen C++17 introduces new rules regarding order of operation. Before then, either side of an assignment could be evaluated first. Since then, the right side has to be evaluated first. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order rule 20.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, that would make much more sense to me. It's a pity NetBeans doesn't support C++17.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a few thing that happens in the expression

```
m[m.size()] = m.size();
```

First, `m[m.size()]` and `= m.size()` need to be evaluated.  In C++14, that evaluation order is indeterminately sequenced.  `m[m.size()]` might happen first, or it might happen second.  If it happens first, then you see the results you received.  If it happens second, then you get the output that you expected.

If you want

```
0 0
1 1
2 2
```

Then you need to guarantee that ordering yourself.  You can use `map::insert()` to do just that:

```
m.insert(m.size(), m.size());
```

---

Starting in C++17, this is no longer the case.  [The standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.ass#1) was changed to say:

> The assignment operator (=) and the compound assignment operators all group right-to-left. All require a modifiable lvalue as their left operand; their result is an lvalue referring to the left operand. The result in all cases is a bit-field if the left operand is a bit-field. In all cases, the assignment is sequenced after the value computation of the right and left operands, and before the value computation of the assignment expression. The right operand is sequenced before the left operand. With respect to an indeterminately-sequenced function call, the operation of a compound assignment is a single evaluation.

It now guarantees that `= m.size()` happens before `m[m.size()]`, and you get the order that you expect.

Comment: Ok, so it is as I suspected then - nothing more funky going on there. Are you saying it is "random" which side is evaluated first (prior to C++17)? Or it's just not obvious due to some convoluted rules? Or it's up to the compiler's optimizations?

Comment: @PetriHirvonen It is up to the compiler to decide which side is evaluated first

Comment: @PetriHirvonen It's "random" in C++14.  Some implementations evaluate the left hand side first and others the right hand side.

Comment: Cppreference calls pre-C++17 evaluation order "indeterminately sequenced". I *think* it's not the same thing as implementation-defined (which would require compilers to document their behavior regarding this).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I've updated the answer to use *indeterminately sequenced*.  I though it was implementation defined but looks like I was remembering the wrong i word.

Answer (score 5):

Let's write down the loop code in a more elaborate way:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    int& temp = m.operator[](m.size());
    temp = m.size();
}
```

Note that calling `operator[]` already does the insertion of an default initialized element before you assign a value to it. Therefore, the map has already grown by the time the right hand side of the assignment is evaluated.

To fix the issue, make sure the size is determined before you use `operator[]`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    size_t v = m.size();
    m[v] = v;
}
```