# Does the modification of the LHS always happen strictly after the RHS has been evaluated during assignment for built-in type?

Tags: c++, variable-assignment, built-in-types

This should be a quite elementary question...

Let `a` be a variable of type `T`, and `f()` be any kind of function which returns `T` (or `T&`, or anything that can be assigned to `T`). Now, assume `f()` does **not** modify `a`. Consider:

```cpp
a = f();
```

For `T` to be a user-defined type, I can be sure that `a` will only be modified after the evaluation of `f()` has finished. Because `a = f();` is a call of the `operator=()` function, and the execution will not go into the function body before the argument is evaluated.

For `T` to be a built-in type, may I ask if the data in `a` is never modified before the evaluation of `f()` is finished?

---

The reason that I would like to confirm this is because I really want to make sure that in any cases where such a `f()` throws an exception, we can safely say that the data in `a` is not corrupted.

Comment: "*For `T` to be a built-in type, may I ask if the data in `a` is never modified before the evaluation of `f()` is finished?*" - yes, that is true. You can't assign something to `a` if that something doesn't exist yet. So `f()` has to be evaluated first, always

Comment: It depends on your version of C++.  In C++17, there is a defined order.  Before that, it is unspecified.

Comment: @NathanOliver The evaluation order doesn't matter here, the compiler is not allowed to write junk to `a` before doing the proper assignment.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It can't write junk, but the order in which each side is resolved can matter, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67233792/inserting-its-own-size-to-stdmap (yes doesn't apply to the OPs specific example)

Comment: @NathanOliver I believe that question confirms that `a` may be evaluated before `f()`, but - pertaining to this question - the `=` is always evaluated after both operands are evaluated.